Get Segwit Bitcoin Address From Simple Private Key (ec_private) Using libbitcoin-system 3.8.0
How can I get the Segwit Bitcoin Address from the ec_private without using HD Keys. My code is as follows and I am quite struggling to use libbitcoin documentation.
#include <bitcoin/system.hpp>

using namespace bc;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    data_chunk seed(16);
    pseudo_random_fill(seed);

    ec_secret secretKey = bitcoin_hash(seed);
    wallet::ec_private wif(secretKey, 0x8000, true);

    string legacyAddress = wif.to_payment_address().encoded();

   // How to get the segwit address?
    ...

    return 0;
}


Use the following function.
string get_segwit_address(ec_private privateKey)
{
    ec_compressed publicKey = privateKey.to_public().point();
    short_hash KeyHash = bitcoin_short_hash(publicKey);
    script P2WPKH = script({operation(opcode(0)), operation(to_chunk(KeyHash))});

    //Create P2SH script
    short_hash WitnessProgramHash = bitcoin_short_hash(P2WPKH.to_data(0));
    script P2SH_P2WPKH = script::to_pay_script_hash_pattern(WitnessProgramHash);

    return payment_address(P2WPKH, payment_address::mainnet_p2sh).encoded();
}


References: http://aaronjaramillo.org

